# What is the difference between a TREK 7.2 FX and a TREK 7.3 FX?

Tags: cross-training, hybrid-bike

I don't understand the numbering system on TREK bikes.

Is it the lower the number the better, or the higher?

What is exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This higher numbers are upgrades.  [Trek website](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/story/fx/)

Upgrades on 7.3 FX from 7.2 FX

```
IsoZone grip and handlebar system
Bontrager Race All-Weather Hard-Case tires
Alloy FX Fork
```

Answer (score 1):

So....Not much.   I'm currently working on one of these, an older 7.3, and it's equipped almost exactly as the 7.2 is now.   Has the steel fork and the regular handlebar grips.   Tires are Bontrager...Don't know which model.

Nice bike, I'm considering keeping it.  (I refurbish bikes for re-sale)

Comment: I am thinking of getting a 7.2 FX, but the 7.3 is cheaper. No bike shops in my area have them both in store, so I need to decide on which one I want before seeing the bike in person.

Comment: @JL01: @ToddPierce's answer covers it pretty well. For the same model year, the 7.3 is better than the 7.2 (but in very minor ways).  Is there some reason you can't go to two bike shops and check them both out?